# cocoon number of nested fields increasing after validation fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, cocoon-gem

Rails 4.2.1, Ruby 2.2.1
Gems: `simple_form`, `cocoon`

Here are the models with relations:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :galleries, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :galleries, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
  validates_presence_of :name
end

class Gallery < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :photos, dependent: :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :photos, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true

  after_initialize :make_photos

  private

  def make_photos
    6.times { photos.build }
  end
end

class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :gallery

  validates :size, presence: true, numericality: { only_integer: true }
end
```

Gallery should have exactly 6 photos, that's why I used `after_initialize` callback to build 6 `photo` objects.

views:

user form

```
  .form-inputs
    = f.simple_fields_for :galleries do |gallery|
      = render 'gallery_fields', f: gallery
    .links
      = link_to_add_association 'add gallery', f, :galleries
```

gallery fields

```
.nested-fields
  = f.simple_fields_for :photos do |photo|
    = render 'photo_fields', f: photo
= link_to_remove_association 'remove photos', f
br
```

photos fields

```
.nested-fields
  = f.input :size
```

If I type correct value in first input and incorrect in others after validation fail the result will be 1 input with filled correct value + 6 empty input fields and so on.

How do I avoid it? I always need to build 6 photos per gallery, if User decided to have one.

I pushed sample app on github, so you can reproduce the problem https://github.com/gabyshev/cocoon_example_increasing_number_of_fields

Comment: What happens when you use `new` method of your controller to build photos instead of `after_initialize`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is because you have 1 valid associated record, and you are still building 6 records, after object is initialized! To avoid you can do following:

```
  def make_photos
    photos.size.upto(6).each { photos.build }
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the `after_initiazlize`. Cocoon helps you to make exactly 6 galleries. You just have to use a little javascript:

with `cocoon:after-insert` you can check if there nested fields are greater than 6 or not, if >=6, then `$('.nested-fields')[1].remove();`.

with `cocoon:after-delete` you can check if there nested fields are less than 6 or not, if < 6, then show add button.

I've done something like that, Hope it helps:

```
<script>
    $('.announcements').on('cocoon:after-insert', function(e, insertedItem) {
        if ($('.nested-fields').length >= 10){
            $('.nested-fields')[1].remove();
        }
    });
    $('.announcements').on('cocoon:after-delete', function(e, insertedItem) {
        if ($('.nested-fields').length < 10){
            $('.add_fields').show();
        }
    });
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".add_news_button").
                data("association-insertion-method", 'after').
                data("association-insertion-node", 'this');
    });
</script>
```